# What part of the react-quilljs object should I save to the database in the backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use [react-quilljs](https://github.com/gtgalone/react-quilljs#with-onchange-handler) to implement text editor in a full mern stack app, but I am not sure what part of the quill object should I save to the database in the backend. I have the follow code for the editor:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useQuill } from 'react-quilljs';
// or const { useQuill } = require('react-quilljs');

import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css'; // Add css for snow theme
// or import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css'; // Add css for bubble theme

export default () => {
  const { quill, quillRef } = useQuill();

  const [content, setContent] = useState('');

  console.log(quill); // undefined > Quill Object
  console.log(quillRef); // { current: undefined } > { current: Quill Editor Reference }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (quill) {
      quill.on('text-change', () => {
        setContent(?) // What part of the quill object I need to use here to set the content before sending it to the backend <-----------------
        console.log(quill.getFormat());
        console.log('Text change!');
      });
    }
  }, [quill]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {//here I will send the editor content to the bakcend};

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 500, height: 300 }}>
      <div ref={quillRef} />
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Use quill.getContents() method to grab the delta (quill editors content) and store this in the database and you can use quill.setContents() method to view it.

Comment: When I tried to view the content using `quill.setContent()` I received this error message `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ops}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` How should I use `quill.setContent()` correctly?

Comment: You have to provide the delta (quill editors content that you stored in database) inside the setContents - 
**setContents(delta: Delta)** 
Though its for js but will help you out in better understanding -[https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents)

Answer (score -2):

You should save two things separately one is Raw data of the Quill and another is extracting only text from it

Refer to the sandbox below , you need to save the content

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-demo-forked-0qr5f?file=/src/editor.js

Comment: Could you be more specific with an example code?

Comment: You can save the content , Please refer this sandbox 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-quill-demo-forked-0qr5f?file=/src/editor.js

You can save the content in the editor , If the text needs to be edited, you need to pass the value of content to react quill , If you need to extract text for view you can use html parser